# Python - Spotipy: How do I grant access permissions to my script to stop getting this error?

Tags: python, caching, spotify, spotipy, oserror

I am trying to get my personal Spotify data for a personal project and am using the Spotipy api to attempt to do so. Mainly following this [article/guide](https://towardsdatascience.com/making-your-own-discover-weekly-f1ac7546fedb), I wrote this code:

```
import spotipy
from spotipy.oauth2 import SpotifyClientCredentials
import spotipy.util as util

cid ="********"
secret = "********"
redirecturi = 'http://localhost:8888'
username = "***"
client_credentials_manager = SpotifyClientCredentials(client_id=cid, client_secret=secret) 
sp = spotipy.Spotify(client_credentials_manager=client_credentials_manager)
scope = 'user-library-read playlist-read-private'
token = util.prompt_for_user_token(username, scope,client_id=cid,client_secret=secret,redirect_uri=redirecturi)
if token:
    sp = spotipy.Spotify(auth=token)
else:
    print("Can't get token for", username)
```

I get an error saying Couldn't read cache at: .cache-"my username" and the python error is this:

```
OSError                                   Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-2-57cc37944df1> in <module>
     16 sp = spotipy.Spotify(client_credentials_manager=client_credentials_manager)
     17 scope = 'user-library-read playlist-read-private'
---> 18 token = util.prompt_for_user_token(username, scope,client_id=cid,client_secret=secret,redirect_uri=redirecturi)
     19 if token:
     20     sp = spotipy.Spotify(auth=token)

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spotipy\util.py in prompt_for_user_token(username, scope, client_id, client_secret, redirect_uri, cache_path, oauth_manager, show_dialog)
     97 
     98     if not token_info:
---> 99         code = sp_oauth.get_auth_response()
    100         token = sp_oauth.get_access_token(code, as_dict=False)
    101     else:

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spotipy\oauth2.py in get_auth_response(self, open_browser)
    437             # Only start a local http server if a port is specified
    438             if redirect_port:
--> 439                 return self._get_auth_response_local_server(redirect_port)
    440             else:
    441                 logger.warning('Using `%s` as redirect URI without a port. '

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spotipy\oauth2.py in _get_auth_response_local_server(self, redirect_port)
    403 
    404     def _get_auth_response_local_server(self, redirect_port):
--> 405         server = start_local_http_server(redirect_port)
    406         self._open_auth_url()
    407         server.handle_request()

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spotipy\oauth2.py in start_local_http_server(port, handler)
   1225 
   1226 def start_local_http_server(port, handler=RequestHandler):
-> 1227     server = HTTPServer(("127.0.0.1", port), handler)
   1228     server.allow_reuse_address = True
   1229     server.auth_code = None

~\anaconda3\lib\socketserver.py in __init__(self, server_address, RequestHandlerClass, bind_and_activate)
    450         if bind_and_activate:
    451             try:
--> 452                 self.server_bind()
    453                 self.server_activate()
    454             except:

~\anaconda3\lib\http\server.py in server_bind(self)
    136     def server_bind(self):
    137         """Override server_bind to store the server name."""
--> 138         socketserver.TCPServer.server_bind(self)
    139         host, port = self.server_address[:2]
    140         self.server_name = socket.getfqdn(host)

~\anaconda3\lib\socketserver.py in server_bind(self)
    464         if self.allow_reuse_address:
    465             self.socket.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
--> 466         self.socket.bind(self.server_address)
    467         self.server_address = self.socket.getsockname()
    468 

OSError: [WinError 10013] An attempt was made to access a socket in a way forbidden by its access permissions
```

Can someone please let me know how I should go about granting access permissions or if there is something else that I am doing wrong? I'm using Jupyter Notebook for this if it makes any difference. Also if you are aware of an easier way to go about getting the data I am after, please let me know.

This is my first post so apologies for any bad practices I have used here.

Answer (score 0):

Try running this in another environment/IDE. Line 310 of `spotipy/oauth2.py` illustrates that `Spotipy` throws this warning if a cache file for tokens has not yet been instantiated.

Comment: Hi Kweks45, thanks for the advice but I tried running the code in Atom and I'm getting the same error. Sorry if this is a stupid question but how do I go about instantiating a cache file for tokens?

Comment: @eolagbaju see , https://github.com/plamere/spotipy/issues/579

Comment: Thanks, I'll give that a try